# How to repair UndefVarError error: ∗ not defined?

Tags: julia

I have a problem, I'm programming a code for the calculation of a simulated economy. However, at the moment of running the model, the coding contains four errors.

The model is running in JuliaBox 1.0.3

```
using Distributions
using DataFrames

# n = numero de familias
# t = numero de periodos para la simulacion

function inequality2(; n =5000 , t =15000 )

# Simulador de la economía e indices de desigualdad %%


    # Parametros de Economia

    gamma   = 2;        # Aversión al riesgo
    delta   = 0.057;    # Depreciación de activos
    betta   = 0.99;     # Factor de descuento
    alfa    = 0.47;     # Elasticidad producto del capital en la producción
    miz     = 1;        # Productividad en estado estacionario 
    roz     = 0.75;     # Ajuste de productividad
    sigmaz  = 0.013;    # Volatilidad de la productividad
    phi     = 0.05;     # Penalización de los hogares (activos)
    rok     = 0.7;      # Parámetro inicial del movimiento de capital
    mie     = 1;        # Empleo en estado estacionatio
    roe     = 0.7;      # Ajuste del empleo
    sigmae1 = 0.05;     # Volatilidad del empleo de los hogares capitalistas
    sigmae2 = 0.1;      # Volatilidad del empelo de los hogares trabajadores
    roez    = 0.3;      # Ciclicidad del empleo para los hogares trabajadores
    lambda  = 0.8;      # Participación de los capitalistas en la economía
    tau     = 0;        # Tasa de impuestos sobre la renta
    ass     = 31.7838916986589918973; # Desviación estandar de los activos
    kss     = lambda*ass;             # Desviación estandar del capital 

    vtheta1 =0.1; # parametro 1 de la ecuación de movimiento de capital
    vtheta2 =0.2; # parametro 2 de la ecuación de movimiento de capital
    vtheta3 =0.3; # parametro 3 de la ecuación de movimiento de capital
    vtheta4 =0.4; # parametro 4 de la ecuación de movimiento de capital
    vtheta5 =0.5; # parametro 5 de la ecuación de movimiento de capital


    n_lambda = trunc(Int, lambda ∗ n)

    eshocks1= rand(Normal(0.0,sigmae1), n_lambda ,t); # choque sobre capitalistas
    eshocks2= rand(Normal(0.0,sigmae2), n-n_lambda , t); # choque sobre capitalistas
    zshocks1= rand(Normal(0.0, sigmaz), 1, t); # choque sobre capitalistas

    # Variables:
    a = ones(t,n);
    c = ones(t,n); 
    y = ones(t,n);
    k = ones(t); 
    w = ones(t); 
    r = ones(t); 
    z = ones(t);
    l = ones(t);
    e = ones(t,n);


    # Valores iniciales de las variables:

    a[1:2,1:n_lambda] = ass ;
    a[1:t,(n_lambda+1):n]=0;
    k[1:2] = lambda∗ass;
    c[1:n_lambda,1] = (assˆalfa)∗(1-tau∗ alfa) - delta∗ass;

    # Loop de Simulacion

    for i = 2:(t-1)
        k[i] = lambda∗mean(a[i,1:n_lambda]);         
        z[i] = (1-roz) + roz∗z[i-1]+zshocks[i];
        l[i] = 1 + (1-lambda)∗roez*(z[i]-1)/(1-roe);
        w[i] = (1-alfa)*z[i]∗((k[i])^(alfa))*l[i]^(-alfa);
        r[i] = alfa∗z[i]*((k[i])^(alfa-1))*l[i]^(1-alfa);
        for j = 1:n_lambda
            e[i,j] = (1-roe) + roe∗e[i-1,j]+eshocks1[j,i];

            a[i+1,j] = (vtheta1) + (vtheta2)*a[i,j]+ (vtheta3)*e[i,j] + (vtheta4)∗z[i] + (vtheta5)∗k[i];


            c[i,j] = (1-tau)∗r[i]∗a[i,j] + w[i]∗e[i,j]+(1-delta )∗a[i,j] - a[i+1,j];


            y[i,j] = (1-tau)∗r[i]∗a[i,j] + w[i]∗e[i,j]; 
        end 

        for m = 1:(n - n_lambda)
            e[i,m+n_lambda] = (1-roe ) + roe∗e[i-1,m+n_lambda]+ roez∗(z[i]-1) + eshocks2[m,i];


            c[i,m+n_lambda] = w[i]∗e[i,m+n_lambda]+ tau∗r[i]∗k[i]/(1-lambda);

            y[i,m+n_lambda] = c[i,m+n_lambda];
        end
    end

    # Preparando las variables para el calculo del indice de Gini

    asort = ones(t,n);
    csort = ones(t,n); 
    ysort = ones(t,n);
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        asort[i,:]=sort(a[i,:]); 
        csort[i,:]=sort(c[i,:]); 
        ysort[i,:]=sort(y[i,:]); 
    end

    # Calculo del Gini de la Riqueza

    giniA = ones(t); 
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        sum1 = 0.0;
        sum2 = 0.0;
        for j = 1:n
            sum1 = (n+1-j)∗asort[i,j] + sum1;
            sum2 = asort[i,j] + sum2;
        end
        giniA[i] = (n+1-2∗(sum1/sum2))/n;
    end

    # Calculo del Gini de Consumo

    giniC = ones(t);
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        sum1 = 0;
        sum2 = 0;
        for j = 1:n
            sum1 = (n+1-j)∗csort[i,j] + sum1;
            sum2 = csort[i,j] + sum2;
        end
        giniC[i] = (n+1-2∗(sum1/sum2))/n;

    end

    # Calculo del Gini de la Renta

    giniY = ones(t);
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        sum1 = 0;
        sum2 = 0;
        for j = 1:n
            sum1 = (n+1-j)∗ysort[i,j] + sum1;
            sum2 = ysort[i,j] + sum2;
        end
    giniY[i] = (n+1-2∗(sum1/sum2))/n;
    end

    # Calculo de la Curva de Lorenz ( lor )

    sum = 0;
    lor = ones(n);
    atrim = asort[t-1,1:n];
    atrim[1:350]=0;
    for i = 1:n
        sum = atrim[i] + sum;
    end
    cum = 0;
    ind = 1:n;
    for i = 1:n
        cum = atrim[i]+cum;
        lor[i] = cum/sum;
    end

    # Calculo del Coeficiente de Theil

    theilY = ones(t);
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        ybar = mean(y[i,:]);
        sum1 = 0;
        for j = 1:n
            sum1 = (y[i,j]/ybar)∗log(y[i,j]/ybar)+sum1;
        end
        theilY[i] = sum1/n;
    end

    # Calculo de Razoes de Porcentajes de Renda

    ratio1 = ones(t);
    r_n = trunc(Int, 0.9 ∗ n)
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        ratio1[i] = ysort[i,r_n]/ysort[i,n - r_n];
    end

    ratio2 = ones(t);
    half_n = trunc(Int, 0.5 ∗ n)
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        ratio2[i] = ysort[i,r_n]/ ysort[i,half_n];
    end

    ratio3=ones(t);
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        ratio3[i] = ysort[i,half_n]/ ysort[i,n - r_n];
    end

    # Calculo de la Decomposicion del Coeficiente de Theil

    theilC = ones(t);
    ytotalC = ones(t);
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        ybarC = mean(y[i,1:n_lambda]);
        sum1 = 0;
        sum2 = 0;
        for j = 1:n_lambda
            sum1 = (y[i,j]/ybarC)∗log(y[i,j]/ybarC)+sum1;
            sum2 = y[i,j] + sum2;
        end
        ytotalC[i] = sum2;
        theilC[i] = sum1/(lambda∗n);
    end

    theilW = ones(t);
    ytotalW = ones(t);
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        ybarW = mean(y[i,(1+n_lambda):n]);
        sum1 = 0;
        sum2 = 0;
        for j = 1:(n - n_lambda)
            sum1 = (y[i,j+n_lambda]/ybarW)∗log(y[i,j+n_lambda]/ybarW)+sum1;
            sum2 = y[i,j+n_lambda]+sum2;
        end
        ytotalW[i] = sum2;
        theilW[i] = sum1/((1-lambda)∗n);
    end

    ytotal = ones(t);
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        sum1 = 0;
        for j = 1:n
            sum1 = y[i,j] + sum1;
        end
        ytotal[i]=sum1;
    end

    shareC = ones(t); 
    shareW = ones(t);
    meanC = ones(t); 
    meanW = ones(t);
    meantotal = ones(t);
    theilCW = ones(t);
    for i = 1:(t-1)
        shareC[i] = ytotalC[i]/ytotal[i]; 
        shareW[i] = ytotalW[i]/ytotal[i];
        meanC[i] = mean(y[i,1:n_lambda]);
        meanW[i] = mean(y[i,(1+n_lambda):n]);
        meantotal[i] = mean(y[i,:]);

        theilCW[i] = shareC[i]∗theilC[i] + shareW[i]∗ theilW[i] + shareC[i]∗log(meanC[i]/ meantotal[i]) + shareW[i]∗log(meanW[i]/ meantotal[i]);


    end


    tab = DataFrame()
    tab[ :periodos] = 15000
    tab[ :familias] = 5000
    tab[ :gamma]     = gamma
    tab[ :delta]   = delta
    tab[ :betta]   = betta
    tab[ :alfa]    = alfa
    tab[ :miz]     = miz
    tab[ :roz]     = roz
    tab[ :sigmaz]  = sigmaz
    tab[ :phi]     = phi
    tab[ :rok]     = rok
    tab[ :mie]     = mie
    tab[ :roe]     = roe
    tab[ :sigmae1] = sigmae1
    tab[ :sigmae2] = sigmae2
    tab[ :roez]   = roez
    tab[ :sigmae1] = sigmae1
    tab[ :sigmae2] = sigmae2
    tab[ :roez]   = roez
    tab[ :lambda] = lambda
    tab[ :tau]    = tau
    tab[ :ass]    = ass
    tab[ :kss]    = kss
    tab[ :GiniY]  = mean(giniY) # valor medio 
    tab[ :GiniC]  = mean(giniC) # valor medio 
    tab[ :GiniA]  = mean(giniA) # valor medio 
    tab[ :TheilY] = mean(theilY) # valor medio 
    tab[ :TheilC] = mean(theilC) # valor medio 
    tab[ :TheilW] = mean(theilW) # valor medio 
    tab[ :TheilCW] = mean(theilCW) # valor medio 
    tab[ :Ratio1] = mean(ratio1) # valor medio 
    tab[ :Ratio2] = mean(ratio2) # valor medio 
    tab[ :Ratio3] = mean(ratio3) # valor medio
    tab[ :ShareC] = mean(shareC) # valor medio 
    tab[ :ShareW] = mean(shareW) # valor medio 
    tab[ :MeanC] = mean(meanC) # valor medio 
    tab[ :MeanW] = mean(meanW) # valor medio 
    tab[ :MeanTotal] = mean(meantotal) # valor medio 

    return tab
end

@time tab = inequality2(n =5000,t =15000);

writetable(”experimento.csv”,tab ,separator=’ ; ’)
```

The following errors occur when running the model:

```
UndefVarError: ∗ not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] #inequality2#13(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Function) at ./In[11]:40
 [2] (::getfield(Main, Symbol("#kw##inequality2")))(::NamedTuple{(:n, :t),Tuple{Int64,Int64}}, ::typeof(inequality2)) at ./none:0
 [3] top-level scope at util.jl:156
 [4] top-level scope at In[11]:297
```

Comment: You'd definitely want to make your example a bit smaller than the above, so that others are more likely to help you. Check this out on how to make a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem is that you are using `∗` instead of `*` as multiplication character. Additionally your code has many other problems that will make it fail. You use `ˆ` instead of `^` for exponentiation. You perform implicit broadcasting, which will fail under Julia 1.0. I.e. you have to write e.g. `a[1:2,1:n_lambda] .= ass` instead of `a[1:2,1:n_lambda] = ass`. Next `zshocks` variable is undefined. Finally the way you create a first row in a `tab` data frame is now deprecated as well as the use of `writetable` function.

Comment: I can help you with all these issues if they are not clear to you, but as @niczky12 suggested better split it into several smaller questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, really if I have problems with the code. I'm not sure because I'm new to Julia. If you help me I would be very grateful for your help @ niczky12 ; @ Bogumił Kamiński.